# Eclipse freezes all the time with Ubuntu

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ubuntu

I have always avoided using Eclipse because I have had nothing but bad experiences with it. I have used it in three different computers, two with Ubuntu 13 and now in a new laptop with Ubuntu 14.

The problem I got is always the same: Eclipse just freezes, stops working. Back then with Eclipse for Java EE developers with some BPEL plugins it just randomly froze every 20 minutes and I had to force close it and it always messed the configuration.

Now I am using Eclipse for Android apps development. First I tried with standard Eclipse, and not only I got a lot of errors in the code with just creating a new Android project, but the interface would dissapear and come back partially when I hovered the mouse over that gone part, but it also froze when it wanted.

Then at some point just creating a new Android project froze the whole program. I just tried downloading Eclipse Java EE and the same thing happens: creating a new Android app project freezes Eclipse and all I get is a half-created, corrupted project.

I tried maximizing the memory Eclipse used and added a little hack I found around StackOverflow that is supposed to help. But none of these solutions did any good.

Here's my `eclipse.ini`:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx2048m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

Any help?

Comment: Try not using the Java EE edition of Eclipse, but rather the standard edition. I have been using Eclipse 3.8 on Ubuntu 14.04 for several months without the degree of issues that you have had, and prior Eclipse/Ubuntu combinations before that. You might also try Google's "ADT Bundle" of Eclipse and the Android Developer Tools plugin.

Comment: @CommonsWare I said the problem happened both with Eclipse JEE and standard Eclipse. I am using ADT plugin.

Comment: You can try Android studio as an alternative for Android development: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the whole content of the workspace, including the `.metadata` folder solved the problem.

Answer (score 16):

I've had a similar problem using Eclipse Luna on my ubuntu 12.04, then I found this blog page http://blog.vogella.com/2014/02/21/using-eclipse-luna-on-ubunbu/ which gave me a solution.

Just create a script:

```
touch eclipse.sh
```

Fill it with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash

export SWT_GTK3=0
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
./eclipse -showlocation
```

Put this script in your eclipse directory then make it executable

```
 chmod +x eclipse.sh
```

and finally run it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I too had similar problems with eclipse when i switched to kubuntu as eclipse kept crashing...Download the latest version of Eclipse from their site which is https://www.eclipse.org/ (Elipse Luna) and install all the required plugins for android development and it should work smoothly....I guess you're using Eclipse juno.